# Python remove attribute from value of dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Imagine the following class:

```py
class ThisObj:
    def __init__(self, kleur, voedsel, isCool, omschrijving):
        self.kleur = kleur
        self.voedsel = voedsel
        self.isCool = isCool
        self.omschrijving = omschrijving
```

I'm creating two instances of this class:

```py
obj1 = ThisObj(12, "graan", False, "Cooleman")
obj2 = ThisObj(13, "water", True, "Gekkeman")
```

I put both instances into a dictionary:

```py
dict = {"AAT_FAN_CORR_VSPD_STEP_MPV": obj1,
        "C_AIM_ct_DPF-DeltaP_X": obj2}
```

I'll do the same for a second dictionary:

```py
obj3 = ThisObj(12, "graan", False, "Watermeloen")
obj4 = ThisObj(14, "ranja", True, "Gekkeman")

dict2  = {"AAT_FAN_CORR_VSPD_STEP_MPV": obj3,
          "C_AIM_ct_DPF-DeltaP_X": obj4}
```

After both dictionaries are filled I want to compare them. But without the "voedsel" attribute. Comparing them should look like this:

```py
del dict["voedsel"]

items = dict ^ dict2
```

This raises a Key error on the delete.

```
KeyError: 'voedsel'
```

So my question is: How do I compare two dictionaries like this while not taking in account one of the attributes of the value. It is not possible to alter the objects before they go into the dictionary, this is because in the real case I'm getting the dictionary from another script which I'm not allowed to change.

Comment: The key `voedsel` to delete is not a key `dict`, but a key of each value inside this dict. Also never name a variable as a built-in word, like `dict`

Comment: @azro I'm aware, but how do I delete a key of each value inside a dict.

Comment: Your `dict` doesn't have `'voedsel'` key. By the way, don't override built-in name `dict`.

Comment: You should use loop. And `voedsel` is not a key, it is an attribute. So when you access it, use `obj.voedsel` not `obj['voedsel']`.

Comment: But is looping also recommended when it's a dictonary of almost 100.000 pairs?

Comment: Can you alter the class definition and define an `__eq__` method?

Comment: @MarkTolonen only when I have a very good reason to..

Comment: Yes I thinks so. But I don't recommend to remove obj's attribute dynamically. It makes harder to debug or to analyse your code.

Comment: How exactly do you want to compare the dictionaries?  `^` (`__xor__`) isn't a dictionary operation.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two objects ignoring one of the attributes, you could define `__eq__` for the comparison:

```
def __eq__(self,other):
    return self.kleur == other.kleur and self.isCool == other.isCool and self.omschrijving == other.omschrijving
```

Then:

```
obj1 = ThisObj(13, "water", True, "Gekkeman")
obj2 = ThisObj(13, "ranja", True, "Gekkeman")
print(obj1 == obj2) # True
```

If this is a one-off comparison and not a defining characteristic of the objects, then you can still manually compare the attributes:

```
def compare(a,b):
    return a.kleur == b.kleur and a.isCool == b.isCool and a.omschrijving == b.omschrijving
```